# How does one know if a namespace in a dynamic or static library is already used?

Tags: c++

In languages like java, a package name is a domain name, like com.foobar.mystuff.

So if you own com.foobar, it is highly unlikely that someone would have used the package name com.foobar, you can be reasonably sure there will not be a collision.

But in c++, you can choose any namespace name. How do you know if a library you are linking to, is not already using a particular namespace name ? Is there a way to test it, especially if you don't have access to source code or documentation ? Is there some guideline to avoid this problem ?

Comment: Hmm, c++ doesn't support any kind of reflection.

Comment: Option 1: Look at the header file, option 2: learn about your compiler ABI, use `strings` or another tool to list all symbol then de-mangling its symbol

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ So I should just use any namespace I like until something crashes ? (and use an alias, so it is easy to change the namespace later?)

Comment: "a package name is a domain name" -- that's a **convention**, not something that the language requires or enforces.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there some guideline to avoid this problem?

While it may surprise you to find that one of the third party libraries you are using uses a `namespace` as your application, it shouldn't cause too much problem, if any.

In the worst case scenario, you'll have to create a `namespace` that is specific to your application and create nested `namespace`s under the main `namespace`.